# in C# how do I convert what I think is a string of hex ascii to something i can read?

Tags: c#, hex, ascii, converters

I have a serial port listener that listens to a device that returns some kind of ascii hex string, like this - ???? followed by some little squiggles that don't paste in here. how do I convert it to something I can read. It should say something like S3.01.063.

Comment: How are you reading in the data. Please show your code.

Comment: what is the device and what is it sending you? i.e. how is the data encoded as bytes? Is it using MODBUS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus for instance?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually trying to send ASCII? Maybe it's just sending bytes that coorelate to some sort of protocol.

Comment: It's this exact code http://csharp.simpleserial.com/

Comment: @Tay, thats how you read the bytes from the port but, how do we or you know how the data that is being sent it encoded into bytes?

Comment: Getting question marks is a very strong indicator that the device doesn't actually return ASCII codes.  Or that you've got basic settings wrong, like the Baudrate.  Contact the device vendor for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure the device is sending hex you could read it as bytes and then convert to hex this way (Based on the link to the code you are using):

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        byte [] bytesRead = new byte[serialPort1.BytesToRead];
        serialPort1.Read(bytesRead, 0, bytesRead.Length);
        RxString = ByteArrayToString(bytesRead);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
        //Console.WriteLine("Hex ouput: {0}", ByteArrayToString(bytesRead)); 
    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
    }

    public string ByteArrayToString(byte[] inBytes)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(inBytes.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in inBytes)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }
```

At least by looking at the byte values being read you will see exactly what is coming into the port.

Comment: Hey, that helps. It returns this, 8f8f8f8f020f01000001114053332e30312e303633d679  And I found a document describing the device communication, but can't share it online, since it's our device and having the details out and about would be really bad.

Comment: OK, stuck again. I was able to remove the preamble of 8f and the 02, but I don't know enough yet about converting these hex values to a string I can read. There is a S3.01.063 in there, and I gather that I have to loop through each hex character and convert it to it's readable value, but the examples I think apply to this are over my head. Do you have some real simple example you could point me to ?

Comment: How about searching for the hex values of S3.01..... (0x53, 0x33, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x31) in your byte array and then you can use the Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byte []) to convert the correct portion of the byte[] a string?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and help, if I write the code,

```
var sBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("S3.01.063");
var bBytes = new byte[] { 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 63 };
```

either could be a perfectly valid binary representation of the data you are expecting but,
if I then write the code,

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(sBytes));
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bBytes));
```

My output will be meaningless drivel. Without knowing how the data is encoded it is difficult to proceed.